# Formatting Chart DataPoints and showing a Label ToolTip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, mschart

This is how my chart looks right now:

[image]

I have these problems:

1. The `AxisX` is a `DateTime` and formated as `Diagramm.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yy HH";`. This is working but as you can see if there are to many hours the label is cut off. How can I set a mouseover tooltip for each label of the X-axis?
2. The series1 is placed on the secondary AxisY2: `Diagramm.Series["S1"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;`. I formated the axis for currency with `Diagramm.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Format = "C0";`

As I understand the given value 1088,55 should be rounded to 1089 € but as you can see it is converted to 108855 €. But why? The value is already given as a double...

**Update for point 2: Thanks to TaW, converted the `,` to `.` and this works**

3. The tooltip for my series1 is created with:

   `foreach (DataPoint dp in Diagramm.Series["S1"].Points)
                   {
                       if (dp.YValues[0] > 0)
                       {
                           dp.ToolTip = dp.YValues[0].ToString("C0") + " Umsatz für Stunde " + dp.AxisLabel.ToString() + "";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                       }
                   }`

I would like to have the hour from the `AxisX` which is formated as `"dd.MM.yy HH"`. How can I access the hour instead of `dp.AxisLabel.ToString()` which is wrong?

**Update for point 3: Thanks to TaW, `DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(dp.XValue.ToString())).Hour` is working**

Thanks

Comment: _1088,55 should be rounded to 1089_ Just a typo, right?

Comment: What about `dp.ToolTip = dp.YValues[0].ToString("C0") + " Umsatz für Stunde " + dp.XValue.ToString("HH") + "";`

Comment: @TaW no not a typo. 1088,55 is my given value and should be rounded to 1089. Actually it change the 1088,55 to 108855 which is wrong

Comment: Sorry I thought I saw one correct value as well but they all are 'wrong'.. Looks like you simply feed them in with decimal point is comma but you need to feed them in with us conventions as `1088.55` !

Comment: @TaW `dp.XValue.ToString("HH")` gives me the value for the tooltip: `"87 € Umsatz für Stunde HH"`. With breakpoint it returns for the `XValue` for example the value `41203.375`. I tried `Convert.ToDateTime(dp.XValue.ToString()).Hour` but gives the error not a valid DateTime

Comment: @TaW I converted the `, ` into `.` and this works for my problem nr. 2. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use to DateTime.ToOADate and FromOADate conversion functions to go from double to datetime and back! Did you define the x-value types?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, `DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(dp.XValue.ToString())).Hour` is working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since parts 2&3 were resolved from the comments we are left with the big one: How can we get tooltips for axis labels.

There are no predefined ones for axis labels it seems. The `Axis` itself does support a `ToolTip` but doesn't accept the [Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx) like `#VALX` etc..

So we need to set its tip value when we hit a `Label`. Here is how we can do that:

We code the `MouseMove` event to test for hitting a `Label`. Then we use the data we find there to create a `ToolTip` string.

It starts rather simple:

- We do the `HittTest`
- We check for having hit one of the `AxisLabels`
- Then we cast the object to `CustomLabel`

This is interesting: We are using plain, automatically created `AxisLabels` but what the `HitTest` returns are `CustomLabels`!!

One of the consequences is that we don't have a `Value` but instead the `ToPosition` and `FromPosition` values. Since the labels were created automatically we can expect them to be arranged symmetrically; so to get the `Value` we can simply take the middle..

Since your x-axis holds `DateTime` converted to `double` as usual  we can now convert back to `DateTime` and format the tip with the same format string you used for the `LabelStyle`. If you want to you could of course pick another format here..

```
private void chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult hit = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.AxisLabels);

    if (hit != null && hit.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.AxisLabels)
    {
        Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        var lab = hit.Object as CustomLabel;
        if (lab == null || lab.Axis != ax) return;
        double d = (lab.ToPosition + lab.FromPosition) / 2d;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d);

        string tip =  dt.ToString(ax.LabelStyle.Format);
        ax.ToolTip = tip; 
    }
}
```

One problem with this is that you need to hit the axis rather well or else the ToolTip won't fire.

[image]

You could avoid this by using a `ToolTip` of your own but this goes beyond the scope of this queston; it would involve a `Timer` you start/stop in the `MouseMove`. you would create the ToolTip string in the `Tick` event and would have to make sure the tip comes and goes nicely..